# Have previous git commit overwrite all similar files of future commit

Tags: git, overwrite

`git log -- onefile` reveals this...

```
d2c2408 - (HEAD, master) yet another fix
5cfc62f - updated web socket for shared blockchain
78bc7b8 - transactions, transaction pool update
b47bf1d - transaction added
d831d08 - added wallet
```

I need for `d831d08` commit to merge into `d2c2408`.

But in the process, I need for the previous commit `d831d08` to overwrite any and all files that future commit has `d2c2408`. Meaning, I want to keep all the future progress that the future commit has but I need to overwrite everything the previous commit has.

What git command do I do this with?

Comment: Not clear to me what you need.

Comment: I would like whatever files previous commit "d831d08  - added wallet" has to overwrite the current commit. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my node_modules caused by installing dependencies between two different environments and pulling these repos instead of installing the dependencies natively for each work environment. Frankly, I'm not skilled enough yet to delve into it. So what I did was simply copy and overwrite the node_modules from the previous commit into the most recent commit. This fixed the nodemon issue of not being able to run my script.

Comment: What it probably was, was that I downloaded a dependency on the other work environment, pulled it into the other and for whatever reason that dependency didn't exist on the new work environment. But NPM believed it did, thus nodemon wouldn't start.